# WebView не отображается на всесь экран

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Такая проблема, при тестировании на эмуляторе, WXGA Android 3.1,  WebView не растягивается на весь экран, а висит небольшим прямоугольником сверху посередине, на планшете 4 дюймовом все ОК и на других разрешениях тоже ОК[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<supports-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) - `android:xlargeScreens="true"` добавить в вашем случае.
Или поставить 4 сдк как минимальный.

Comment: android:xlargeScreens выдает ошибку,
сделал так и все заработало: 
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"          android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"            android:anyDensity="true"/>